# Having Issues converting mysql datetime to javascript date

Tags: javascript, mysql, timestamp

I am trying to convert mysql datetime into javascript datetime. having issues. does not return the correct date.

```
$('#ProjectExtendDeadline').change(function(){
    var oldDate = $('#ProjectOldDeadline').val();
    var t = oldDate.split(/[- :]/);
    var days = $('#ProjectExtendDeadline').val();

    var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
    var date = d.getDate()+" "+d.getMonth()+" "+d.getFullYear();
});
```

[image: Here is the values I get back. I the date is clearly 3 but shows as 2]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. The `getMonth` method returns a zero-based month (0 .. 11).

---

Likewise the `Date` constructor wants a zero-based month, so your code is correct as the value from the database is 1-based.

```
var d = new Date(2012,0,3);
document.write(d);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Tue Jan 03 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function mysqlTimeStampToDate(timestamp) {
    //function parses mysql datetime string and returns javascript Date object
    //input has to be in this format: 2007-06-05 15:26:02
    var regex=/^([0-9]{2,4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9]) (?:([0-2][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))?$/;
    var parts=timestamp.replace(regex,"$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6").split(' ');
    return new Date(parts[0],parts[1]-1,parts[2],parts[3],parts[4],parts[5]);
  }
```

[Source](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4132)

ps: Oh, I see your confusion :) Yep, month = 2 is March. Just make alert(d) and you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. STUPID MISTAKE.

The second parameter `t[1]-1` has a -1. had to remove. sorry.

Comment: No - the month value in the `Date` constructor is also zero based (0 == January) so your code is completely correct as it stands. I've edited my answer to demonstrate.